# node.js ( how to create express)

Tags: node.js, express

```
lee-ui-MacBook-Pro:test1 ErinLee$ sudo npm install -g express
Password:
express@4.9.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── finalhandler@0.2.0
├── vary@1.0.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── methods@1.1.0
├── serve-static@1.6.3
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@0.4.5
├── qs@2.2.4
├── on-finished@2.1.0 (ee-first@1.0.5)
├── etag@1.4.0 (crc@3.0.0)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.3 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.3)
├── accepts@1.1.1 (negotiator@0.4.8, mime-types@2.0.2)
├── send@0.9.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11)
├── type-is@1.5.2 (mime-types@2.0.2)
└── debug@2.0.0 (ms@0.6.2)
lee-ui-MacBook-Pro:test1 ErinLee$ express
-bash: express: command not found
lee-ui-MacBook-Pro:test1 ErinLee$ express test1
-bash: express: command not found
lee-ui-MacBook-Pro:test1 ErinLee$
```

what's wrong?? why i can't create express??
i'm in terminal on mac os X

Answer (score 1):

**express** is a **node.js** module.

You are looking for the **express generator**:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

https://github.com/expressjs/generator

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also please take a look at express guide http://expressjs.com/guide.html